# Restore whatsapp Google Drive backup on different number

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I have all my whats app data backed up on Google Drive. Two days ago my phone stopped working and now I have a new one with a different number(cause I lost the simcard with the number I was using for whats app).

From the F.A.Q I can read that the "restore" option is available only if the number is the same, there's no other way to restore my old chat or at least read them? The google account is the same...

Comment: How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry that method called for having the encrypted file from the previous device which you don't have. This won't work. Didn't read that fully before commenting